# Allocate memory for 2d array to print a matrix using functions, in C89

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, allocation, c89

Hello I had to write a program (well still have) that would allocate memory in function for storing numbers that you have to input then print a matrix (rows and columns are the same size). Most importantly the program has to be written using pointers, local variables, functions and C 89 standard.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void Matrix_Input(int *m, int ***Matrix);
    void Matrix_Output(int m, int **Matrix);

    int main()
    {
        int m;
        int **Matrix;
        int i;
        Matrix_Input(&m, &Matrix);
        Matrix_Output(m, Matrix);

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) /*free memory*/
            free(*(Matrix+i));
        free(Matrix);
        return 0;
    }
    void Matrix_Input(int *m, int ***Matrix)
    {
        int i, j;
        printf("Input number of rows/columns: \n");
        scanf("%d", m);
        *Matrix = malloc(*m* sizeof(int*)); /*allocate memory*/
        for (i = 0; i < *m; i++)
            *(*Matrix+i) = malloc(*m* sizeof(int));
        printf("Input integers: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < *m; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < *m; j++)
                scanf("%d", &((*Matrix)[i][j]));
    }
    void Matrix_Output(int m, int **Matrix)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                printf("%5d", Matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

The program works fine, but I was asked not to use triple pointers here(for input function):

```
    void Matrix_Input(int *m, int ***Matrix)
```

Teacher told me to use double pointers for input function just like I did for output like this:

```
    void Matrix_Input(int *m, int **Matrix)
```

And this is where everything goes wrong since I only know how to allocate with triple pointers. I have to leave input as a separate function, can't put it in main.

Could someone help me out? Please.

Comment: "*use double pointers for input function just like I did for output*": If not returning the double pointer as function value (as pointed out by [Matthieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907523/694576)) then this is only possible if you let the caller of the function allocate the array, or at least its 1st dimension.

Comment: It makes me cringe when people are forced to learn to code to an almost 30-year old standard.  The software industry is supposed to be dynamic and continually improving things.  Continuing to teach C89 is, frankly, close to ludicrous.

Comment: Can't disagree there. I was quite sad when we were told to use c89, makes learning harder since there is less relevant information on the Internet. Maybe that's the point, just make it harder.

Comment: You are aware, that what you call a 2D NxN array in fact are 1+N 1D arrays of dimension N, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Return your Matrix pointer instead. It's an output to the function, not a real input.

```
int** Matrix_Input(int* n)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked So there is no way to write that function with "int **Matrix" in it lite this: void Matrix_Input(int *m, int **Matrix) ?

Comment: No, because you have to allocate it inside, and you need to return this pointer tot eh calling function.